# C++ how can I balance the brackets after the macro call?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic

```cpp
#define function(...) [](){ DO_STUFF(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Because of the open bracket in the macro, I'm left with an ugly usage with either a missing bracket or an extra bracket. Is there a way to fix this?

```cpp
function(a, b, c)
    foo();
}
```

```cpp
function(a, b, c){
    foo();
}}
```

Comment: _"Is there a way to fix this?"_ - Don't use macros?

Comment: A "typical" way to do this would be to have another macro: `#define end_function }`. However, is this really the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do? Macros like this can often make it harder to understand what's going on, and it's not particularly C++-like.

Comment: I would argue that *all* macro usage leaves you with ugly usage :)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why is this tagged as `C`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It definitely is.

Comment: Are you trying to make C++ look like JavaScript? The macro system of C++ is too primitive for any real syntax transformation.

Comment: It looks like you want to be able to do `auto x = function(a) {return a+5;}`, which is basically saying "I'd rather be writing javascript.". This might make coding easier for you right now, but I guarantee that it will make your code a lot harder to read for anyone else (possibly including your future self).

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript, just use JavaScript ;)

Comment: To paraphrase Jamie Zawinski (who was paraphrasing D. Tilbrook), "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think *I know, I'll use macros.* Now they have two problems."  Macros are The Devil™.

Comment: JavaScript also has scoping rules different than C++.  Basically don't try to do line-by-line translations from one language to C++.  Otherwise you'll end up with C++ code that is either buggy, not optimal, hard-to-debug, or just plain weird-looking for a C++ programmer.

Comment: If you tell us what you are actually trying to do, we might be able to help you better. But you try to butcher the syntax of C++ with macros. The obvious solution is to _not_ use macros and accept the syntax as it is or use a different language.

Comment: @churill I'm most of the way through writing a JS to C++ transpiler. I'm just trying to add some syntactic sugar.

Comment: Oof C++ has enough syntactic sugar as it is

Comment: BTW there was no sarcasm in any comment that I can see. Advising against an approach is not the same as "not knowing how" to do it - reverse psychology won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of lambda capture initializers which were introduced in c++14:

```
template <class...Args>
int do_stuff(Args&& ... args)
{
    ((std::cout << args),...); // <-this requires c++17 and is just for illustration.
    return 1;
}

#define myfunction(...) [dummy##__LINE__=do_stuff(__VA_ARGS__)]()

int main() {    

    auto f = myfunction(1,2,3,4,5){std::cout<< "balanced" << std::endl;};
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12345balanced
```

Here's a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eJsjsE). For that to work `do_stuff` has to return something else than void.

**WARNING** I am not sure if the compiler is allowed to remove unused captured values.

Comment: Not really seeing the utility of this. You pass (then discard, or in your example, arbitrarily `cout`) values, rather than accepting arguments into the encapsulated function. It's not really accomplishing anything.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Well, it does exactly what was asked for. A function do_stuff(__VA_ARGS__) is called and the final syntax has balanced curly braces . In the original question the lambda hidden by the macro does not pass any arguments nor does it capture arguments. It simply executes a function and then you can do other unrelated things in the same lambda function body.

Comment: Thank you, the following was exactly what I needed

    #define function(...) [DO_STUFF(__VA_ARGS__)]()

Comment: @MorganGethinBarrett As I have written, I am not sure if the compiler is allowed to remove the function call `do_stuff`. So, at some point this might stop working. Therfore, as the others here, I rather recommend you to stick to the c++ syntax.

Comment: @StefanKssmr DO_STUFF is a macro, that doesn't replace it with anything weird, so I think it should be okay

Comment: @MorganGethinBarrett Does DO_STUFF have a return value? Have you tested the above code with your macro?